# Checking input type in JS

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, if-statement, typeof

I'm using the typeof command to make sure that only 1 of the 2 input fields of this temperature (Celsius to/from Fahrenheit) calculator is populated with data and it has to be a number. If the input is not a valid number or both fields are populated, the app will throw an error message.

The problem: nothing satisfies this condition - the errorMessage is always shown, even if I type in a valid number.

Is **typeof** the right solution to this problem? If it is, why is this code not working?

```
document.getElementById('temperature-form').addEventListener('submit', calculateResult);

function calculateResult(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const celsiusInput = document.getElementById('celsius');
    const fahrenheitInput = document.getElementById('fahrenheit');
    let resultOutput = document.getElementById('result');
    // validate input data type and calculate result  
    if ((typeof celsiusInput === 'number') && (fahrenheitInput === null)) { 
        resultOutput.value = (celsiusInput.value * 1.8 + 32) + ' Fahrenheit';
    } else if ((celsiusInput === null) && (typeof fahrenheitInput === 'number')) {
        resultOutput.value = ((fahrenheitInput.value - 32)/1.8) + ' Celsius';  
    } else {
        errorMessage('Please add a number in one of these fields');
    } 
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: A DOM Element would not be a number.  You could have a `<input type="number">` where the type attribute would be number, but the typeof of the Element would not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the value properties of each input to see if they are numbers using the `isNaN()` function like so:

```
function calculateResult(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get the value of each input box
    const celsiusValue = document.getElementById('celsius').value;
    const fahrenheitValue = document.getElementById('fahrenheit').value;
    //Get the result element
    let resultOutput = document.getElementById('result');

    // validate input data type and calculate result  
    if(!isNaN(celsiusValue) && (fahrenheitValue === null || fahrenheitValue === "")){
        //Only celsiusValue has a valid number
        resultOutput.value = (celsiusValue * 1.8 + 32) + ' Fahrenheit';
    }else if(!isNaN(fahrenheitValue ) && (celsiusValue === null || celsiusValue === "")){
        //Only fahrenheitValue has a valid number
        resultOutput.value = ((fahrenheitValue - 32)/1.8) + ' Celsius';  
    }else if(!isNan(celsiusValue) && !isNan(fahrenheitValue )){
       //Both contain a valid number
       //Figure this one out as you didn't account for it
    }else{
       //Neither is a valid number
       errorMessage('Please add a number in one of these fields');
    } 
}
```

Documentation of `isNaN()`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Thanks very much! That did the trick. I tried .value before but it didn't work because typeof was not the right tool here. !isNaN was the key :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When doing `const celsiusInput = document.getElementById('celsius')` you're getting the [DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), not the value.
In order to obtain de value you'd have to check for the property [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value).

So you'd end up with something like this:

```
const celsiusInput = document.getElementById("celsius")
const celsiusValue = celsiusInput.value
```

Now if we do `typeof celsiusValue` we'll always get `string`, because text/number inputs always accept text (check input's [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#type) property for more info).

The proper way to check if there are numbers or letters is using [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

I'll leave a simple example to act as a starting point for you:

```
const celsiusInput = document.getElementById("celsius")
const celsiusValue = celsiusInput.value
if(/\D/.test(celsiusValue)) {
  alert("There is something that's not a number in the Celsius input!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Well, it's a whole new galaxy for me. Researching now to get a grasp on regExp...

Answer (score 0):

First of by doing a comparison like this `fahrenheitInput === null` you're comparing a DOM element against the value null.

That will only evaluate to true if the DOM Element never existed.

Secondly the typeof method will always evaluate to a **String** on DOM element types, so again this will always be false.

To really get what you want you have to do a proper check

1. To check if both input fields are supplied, simply checking the length of the values will surface:

```
if(fahrenheitInput.length > 0 && celsiusInput.length > 0) //fail
```

2. If fahrenheitInput only is given:

```
if(!isNaN(Number(fahrenheitInput)) //convert
```

3. if celsiusInput only is given:

```
if(!isNaN(Number(celsiusInput)) //convert
```

4. Finally if all checks above don't check our, fail